# Exiting a function with trap and its error code

Tags: bash, function, bash-trap

Let's assume I have the following function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

f(){
    trap 'printf "\nAborting\n"; return 1' SIGINT
    sleep 10
    return 0
}
```

If I run `f` and wait those 10 seconds and then do

```
$ echo $?
> 0
```

That's expected. But if I run `f` and hit `Ctrl+c`, the function `f` is aborted, but

```
$ echo $?
> 0
```

instead of `1`. I assume I'm not trapping properly, but don't how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use `exit` instead of `return`. So this would be

```
trap 'printf "\nAborting\n"; exit 1' SIGINT
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem I have with this solution is when I source the script with the function, it will also source the [tag:trap] condition, i.e. when I hit `Ctrl+c`, it will close my shell. The solution, of course, is to *not* source the script, but I tried to make the script also working for users that will source it.

Comment: As long as you have the trap inside a function, the function will be parsed, of course, but not executed. Consequently, the trap will not be active, unless you call the function.